# Use asyn method for synchronous Sqlite on createMethod

Tags: sqlite, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm using Xamarin, also my SQLite tables contain a large amount of data.

Because I want to avoid UIThread problems in `OnCreate()`, I need to perform database actions asynchronously.

I'm looking for guidance if I am handling this properly.

**First method**, which I found on the net:

```cs
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{           
    base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

    SetContentView(Resource.Layout.InventoryPreviewMain);

    Thread thread = new Thread(() =>
    {
        SQLiteConnection db = new SQLiteConnection(dpPath);

        var table = db.Query<InventoryPreviewClass>("select * from InventoryPreviewClass where CategoryID =" + Connection.CategoryID + "");

        mItems = new List<InventoryPreviewClass>();

        foreach (var item in table)
        {
            mItems.Add(new InventoryPreviewClass() { InventoryItemID = item.InventoryItemID, InventoryItemName = item.InventoryItemName, InventoryItemPrice = item.InventoryItemPrice });
        }

        MyListViewAdapterInventory adapter = new MyListViewAdapterInventory(this, Resource.Layout.InventoryPreview, mItems);
        mlistview.Adapter = adapter;
    });
    thread.Start();
```

**Second Method**, using `async`

```cs
public async void StartTimer()
{
    SQLiteConnection db = new SQLiteConnection(dpPath);

    var table = db.Query<InventoryPreviewClass>("select * from InventoryPreviewClass where CategoryID =" + Connection.CategoryID + "");

    mItems = new List<InventoryPreviewClass>();

    foreach (var item in table)
    {
        mItems.Add(new InventoryPreviewClass() { InventoryItemID = item.InventoryItemID, InventoryItemName = item.InventoryItemName, InventoryItemPrice = item.InventoryItemPrice });
    }

    MyListViewAdapterInventory adapter = new MyListViewAdapterInventory(this, Resource.Layout.InventoryPreview, mItems);
    mlistview.Adapter = adapter;

    await Task.Delay(500);
}
```

Which of two examples are more safe for keeping alive UIthread? Is there any other solution for making this?What is more reccomended to do?

Answer (score 0):

## Answer

Use the [Cross-platform SQLite Library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/sqlite-net-pcl/) made by [@FrankKruger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/338/frank-krueger) to create/access SQLite databases for Xamarin mobile apps.

This library has a built-in asynchronous connection, so you'll never need to worry about accessing the database from the UI Thread again!

## Xamarin.Android Example

#### "Second Method"

```cs
public async Task StartTimer()
{
    mItems = await InventoryPreviewClassDatabase.GetAllInventoryPreviewClassAsync();

    MyListViewAdapterInventory adapter = new MyListViewAdapterInventory(this, Resource.Layout.InventoryPreview, mItems);
    mlistview.Adapter = adapter;
}
```

#### BaseDatabase Class

```cs
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using SQLite;

namespace SampleApp
{
    public abstract class BaseDatabase
    {
        #region Constant Fields
        static readonly Lazy<SQLiteAsyncConnection> _databaseConnectionHolder = new Lazy<SQLiteAsyncConnection>(() => GetDatabaseConnection());
        #endregion

        #region Fields
        static bool _isInitialized;
        #endregion

        #region Properties
        static SQLiteAsyncConnection DatabaseConnection => _databaseConnectionHolder.Value;
        #endregion

        #region Methods
        protected static async Task<SQLiteAsyncConnection> GetDatabaseConnectionAsync()
        {
            if (!_isInitialized)
                await Initialize().ConfigureAwait(false);

            return DatabaseConnection;
        }

        static async Task Initialize()
        {
            await DatabaseConnection.CreateTableAsync<InventoryPreviewClass>().ConfigureAwait(false);
            _isInitialized = true;
        }

        SQLiteAsyncConnection GetDatabaseConnection()
        {
            var sqliteFilename = "YourDatabaseName.db3";
            string documentsPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal); // Documents folder
            var path = Path.Combine(documentsPath, sqliteFilename);

            var conn = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(path, SQLiteOpenFlags.ReadWrite | SQLiteOpenFlags.Create | SQLiteOpenFlags.SharedCache);

            return conn;
        }
        #endregion

    }
}
```

#### Parent Database Class

```cs
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace SampleApp
{
    public abstract class InventoryPreviewClassDatabase : BaseDatabase
    {
        #region Methods    
        public static async Task<IList<InventoryPreviewClass>> GetAllInventoryPreviewClassAsync()
        {
            var databaseConnection = await GetDatabaseConnectionAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

            return await databaseConnection.Table<InventoryPreviewClass>().ToListAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
        }

        public static async Task<InventoryPreviewClass> GetInventoryPreviewClassByIDAsync(int id)
        {
            var databaseConnection = await GetDatabaseConnectionAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

            return await databaseConnection.Table<InventoryPreviewClass>().Where(x => x.ID.Equals(id)).FirstOrDefaultAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
        }

        public static async Task<int> SaveInventoryPreviewClassAsync(InventoryPreviewClass inventoryPreview)
        {
            var databaseConnection = await GetDatabaseConnectionAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
            
            var isObjectInDatabase = await GetInventoryPreviewClassByIDAsync(inventoryPreview.ID).ConfigureAwait(false) != null;

            if (isObjectInDatabase)
                return await databaseConnection.UpdateAsync(inventoryPreview).ConfigureAwait(false);

            return await databaseConnection.InsertAsync(inventoryPreview).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }

        public static async Task<int> DeleteItemAsync(OpportunityModel opportunity)
        {
            var databaseConnection = await GetDatabaseConnectionAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

            return await databaseConnection.DeleteAsync(opportunity).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }

        public static async Task<int> GetNumberOfRowsAsync()
        {
            var databaseConnection = await GetDatabaseConnectionAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

            return await databaseConnection.Table<InventoryPreviewClass>().CountAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

This code was inspired from [this Xamarin.Forms sample app](https://github.com/brminnick/InvestmentDataSampleApp)

Comment: I'm already user this sqlite by @Frank. Should i create these two classes in my apk? Or they are embeded in my sqlite compoment?

Comment: Yes, copy/pase the BaseDatabase and Parent Database classes into your Xamarin.Android project. I added an example that shows how to access the database using your second method.

Comment: Is there any easiest way? Just placing  my existing code inside in an ansync Method? Or just to create a new thread and running my code inside there